# Why is charAt invoked when calling capitalize with arguments in Scala

Tags: scala

```
scala> "Foo".capitalize(2)    
res18: Char = o
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copied from the [StringLike trait doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.StringLike):

```
def capitalize: String
Returns this string with first character converted to upper case
```

What you are actually doing is

"Foo".capitalize.apply(2)

The docs again:

```
def apply(n: Int): Char
Return element at index n
```

Comment: which evaluates to the same as `"Foo"(2)`, which is the same as `Predef.augmentString("Foo").apply(2)` by way of implicit conversion which calls `charAt`.

Comment: Exactly. To be honest got a little lazy when it came to find the implicit method involved.